# Spring Many to Many from one model to different models

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am a bit new with Spring and trying to find a flexible and right way to implements such thing:

I have model TAG which can be connected with different models (Car, Bicycle, Bike, etc.):
[image]

How to implement such relation?
FYI: If I want to delete Tag instance, I am interested in deleting all relations to this tag from Car, Bicycle, etc, but not delete Car, Bicycle instances

Comment: I would suggest to use unidirectional `@ManyToMany` or even a simple `@ElementCollection` for the tagging functionality. Ask yourself how often tag deletion is going to happen

Comment: I agree that not often, but there is still a need